# Optional keys with yaml-cpp 0.5.1

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13168137/1527126) describes how to check if a key exists in a yaml node using `YAML::Node::FindValue("parameter")`.

Unfortunately, I can't call this in the latest version (0.5.1):

```
 error: ‘class YAML::Node’ has no member named ‘FindValue’
```

Is this expected to work or is there an equivalent function which works in the latest version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the new API, you can just check:

```
if (node["parameter"]) {
  // ...
}
```

It may be convenient to define an object in the `if (...)` block:

```
if (YAML::Node parameter = node["parameter"]) {
  // process parameter
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Now you've spelled it out I see that's the first step in the tutorial. oops.

Comment: But doesn't `node["parameter"]` add an entry to the bottom-level containers potentially increasing the used memory? Reading the implementation of version `0.7.0` it seems to me  that `emplace_back` is called on a couple of `std::map` members. I am not saying it matters/should be different, but I am not sure this is leaving node totally identical.

Comment: so would it be a bad idea to use a const reference like this:

`void foo(const YAML::Node& node) {
  if (node) {
    ...
  }
}

foo(node["parameter"])`